# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout when login in

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, android-adapterview

I am trying to link a list to a Category for each car with the use of Firebase, but saddly when I login to the application the Categories and the Cars fail to appear and all I am left with is a blank Screen.

[Database is Here][1]

**Error Log**

```
  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**Home Activity**

```
package com.cars.evd.dealership.main;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Common.Common;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.Model.Category;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.ViewHolder.CarViewHolder;
import com.cars.evd.dealership.main.ViewHolder.DealershipViewHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtFullName;

    //Load Menu
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    //Firebase Adapter
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,CarViewHolder> adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: Checked the answers but didnt solve it.
I believe it has something to do with the values among the fields, but I cant be sure. I have tried all the possibilities but without much success.

Answer (score 0):

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

This is because you haven't initialize the adapter and add it to the RecyclerView when you don't find any `CarCategoryID`:

```
//Get intent here
if(getIntent() != null)
    CarCategoryID = getIntent().getStringExtra("CarCategoryID");

// here is the problem
if(!CarCategoryID.isEmpty() && CarCategoryID !=null){
    loadCarsList(CarCategoryID);
}
```

when you checking string with `CarCategoryID.isEmpty()` it will also check if the string is contain only `""`. Because you initializing the `CarCategoryID` and you don't have any `intent`, the `loadCarsList` method won't be called and you won't attach the adapter.

Comment: How would you suggest me to Initialize and add it?